# Conversion from au to mas

Tags: orbit, astronomical-unit

I am trying to verify whether the third column is correct. The second column is radius of orbit with period corresponding to Gaia DR2 observing window duration.

```
d_pc         OrbG2  Orb_mas
99.32459277  1.905  0.356777803
431.7789292  2.689  6.227724
7751.937984  5.74   0.74046
35.25471532  1.583  0.835263191
346.2603878  2.631  7.598328
```

What is wrong with this conversion, please?

[image]

I obtained this instead of the third column:

```
0      19.179401
1       6.227679
2       0.740455
3      44.901469
4       7.598273
```

Comment: You have to be a bit more verbose in what you do. Just writing a formula without explanation doesn't cut it. What are the columns and your units in your table, and are they what you think they are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conversion is correct, and Python agrees with you:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy import units as u
d = np.array([99.32459277,
             431.7789292,
            7751.937984,
              35.25471532,
             346.2603878]) * u.pc
D = np.array([1.905,
              2.689,
              5.74,
              1.583,
              2.631]) * u.AU
theta = D/d * u.rad
for t in theta:
    print('{:9.6f}'.format(t.to(u.mas)))
```

which outputs

```
19.179540 mas
 6.227724 mas
 0.740460 mas
44.901795 mas
 7.598328 mas
```

You should probably check what the third column actually represents.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Anna-Kat You're welcome! If you don't yet know `astropy` (in particular its use of units), I highly recommend starting to use it. It's a fantastic tool, under continuous development, and well documented :)